# How to generate a PDF within application with no reporting framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation, export

I need to create pdf reports in my app. I'm using asp.net mvc3. What's the best way to do this? I don't really want to use a reporting framework if i can avoid it, it's just a few reports, table layout, groupings, pagination possibly, totals, ability to merge pdfs into 1 pdf....any ideas? what would be ideal is if i could convert my html view into a pdf simply...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into .NET allowing to create PDF files. So you have two possibilities: write one yourself from scratch or use one that exists.

In case you decide to go with the second you may take a look at [flying-saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) which along with [ikvmc.exe](http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html) could be used to convert XHTML files into PDF. I have [blogged](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/76-how-to-convert-xhtml-to-pdf-in-c.html) about some  of the required steps in order to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities:

I think you can do this with SQL Server reporting services (in SQL rather than a 3rd party reporting framework)

Low level PDF libraries that can be used: PDFSharp, iTextSharp.

You could print an html file to a postscript driver using word automation, then convert the PS to PDF via GhostScript

Comment: Thanks, do PDFSharp and iTextSharp support multiple pages and merging multiple pdfs?

Comment: They both support multiple pages, you can merge with iTextSharp, not sure about PDFSharp

Comment: How can I get iTextSharp to convert html into a pdf? any tutorials specific to exporting an html mvc3 view?

Comment: iTextSharp doesnt support converting html to PDF, this is a low level library that can be used to generate PDF using code.

Comment: ...although a quick search reveals this thread, which might help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1199774.aspx